# Node Red UI template how to clear cache

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-red

Hi i have a UI template node like this

```
[{"id":"a5c1aeec.acf41","type":"ui_template","z":"317f5671.321bea","group":"7390bf6e.e7d18","name":"alert","order":0,"width":"","height":"","format":"<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Expires\" content=\"-1\" />\n\n<div></div>\n<script>\n\n(function(scope) {\n    scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n                alert(msg.payload);\n                 return msg;\n    });\n  \n})(scope);\n  \n</script>\n\n","storeOutMessages":false,"fwdInMessages":false,"templateScope":"local","x":930,"y":540,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"ea160087.f05fd","type":"inject","z":"317f5671.321bea","name":"","topic":"","payload":"hello","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":704,"y":539,"wires":[["a5c1aeec.acf41"]]},{"id":"7390bf6e.e7d18","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"info","tab":"3b15c8d0.06c048","order":5,"disp":false,"width":"9","collapse":false},{"id":"3b15c8d0.06c048","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"config","icon":"settings","order":4}]
```

When i do page reload this is executing with previous value though no "msg.payload" passed to it. 
can anyone help me how to clear the cache or on reload this should not show any alert.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a variable and skip the alert if it's not set like so:

```
(function(scope) {
scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
            if(typeof(window.lastAlert)=="undefined"){
                window.lastAlert = msg;
            }else{
                alert(msg.payload);
            }
            return msg;
});
```

This worked on my end using chrome.  You may have to clear your browser cache after you update your flow. (Ctrl + F5 in chrome)

```
[{"id":"14e8dc7a.390aa4","type":"ui_template","z":"98c20df4.95abc","group":"d1f187ec.103688","name":"alert","order":0,"width":"","height":"","format":"<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Expires\" content=\"-1\" />\n\n<div></div>\n<script>\n\n(function(scope) {\n    scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n                if(typeof(window.lastAlert)==\"undefined\"){\n                    window.lastAlert = msg;\n                }else{\n                    alert(msg.payload);\n                }\n                return msg;\n    });\n})(scope);\n\n</script>\n\n","storeOutMessages":false,"fwdInMessages":false,"templateScope":"local","x":690,"y":360,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"c59c7cc4.0593e","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"hello","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":510,"y":360,"wires":[["14e8dc7a.390aa4"]]},{"id":"d1f187ec.103688","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"info","tab":"aa1700c2.78e64","order":5,"disp":false,"width":"9","collapse":false},{"id":"aa1700c2.78e64","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"config","icon":"settings","order":4}]
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. and normal alert also not showing.

Comment: what browser/os are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome & windows 7,
I have resolved this by storing flag in local storage. i.e set local storage in one template and before giving alert i am checking that flag if it is true then only showing an alert.